# cannot find protocol declaration for NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was creating an `NSObject` class for doing web service. But while creating the protocol ,an error comes displaying"cannot find protocol declaration for `NSObject`" .In Xcode 4 I never came across such problems.Now I am using Xcode 6. Pls help me. Code is as below.

```
@protocol web <NSObject>
-(void)(NSArray *)urlArray;    
@end

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Webclass : NSObject    
@end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Write your protocol under #import and put name on your method

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol web <NSObject>
-(void)methodName:(NSArray *)urlArray;
@end
@interface Webclass : NSObject
@end
```